# Trigger window Logon on a remote machine as a different user

Tags: blueprism, rpa

i have been searching around for a while to find a way to Trigger a logon on a remote machine as a different user.

This is for an Blueprism RPA requirement. We have few virtual machines that run RPA processes and these machines will need to be logged in with the bot account for the processes to run. We have a Login agent that can be used to trigger logons on the machines, but they need to be done per machine basis which can sometimes be time consuming.

I can remote login to those machine to initiate the logons, but the automation fails if I close the session due to some display thingy.

If there is something like a command that I can trigger from my CMD that would do the job for me would be of great help

TIA

Comment: Have you tried installing the Login Agent component...? In any case, please consider revising the body of your question - "*some display thingy*" is not particularly descriptive of your problem.

Comment: "_but the automation fails if I close the session due to some display thingy_" - this is probably due to using a program like Microsoft Remote Desktop, as the session it creates runs in the background. If you use a program that connects to the console session - such as VNC or TeamViewer - then this won't be a problem. That being said, it's best to set up the logins automatically, like with Andrzej's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to ensure that the machine is logged in, before the process start, then you can build it in into the scheduler.

Set the first step in the process as "login" and no matter if it completes or fails, after set amount of time run the process.

[image: login action]
[image: process action]

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to get this done using AutomateC.exe utility that comes with Blueprism. You can pretty much run any process on any VM and also specify input parameters. This is pretty handy when there is a need to interact with too many VMs.